# Is there a solution to activate Flash in Firefox 56?

Tags: firefox, flash

[image: missing flash]

In Linux ubuntu 16.04, When I open a page that uses or works with FLASH, nothing appears in the flash content and in the plugins everything is fine, flash is in mode (ACTIVATE ALWAYS) and nothing happens, before there was no problem, but in the update to version 56 this problem happens. Is there any solution???? I like to use Firefox and need flash.
[Check The Image to can understand better what is happening]

I appreciate your help and your Answers!

PS: Sorry about the bad translate of english!

```
sudo dpkg -l adobe-flashplugin [sudo] password for jeisson: 

Deseado=desconocido(U)/Instalar/eliminaR/Purgar/retener(H) 
| Estado=No/Inst/ficheros-Conf/desempaqUetado/medio-conF/medio‌​-inst(H)/espera-disp‌​aro(W)/pendienTe-dis‌​paro 
|/ Err?=(ninguno)/requiere-Reinst (Estado,Err: mayúsc.=malo) 
||/ Nombre Versión Arquitectura Descripción  
+++-==============-============-============-===============‌​================== 
ii adobe-flashplu  1:20170912.1 amd64        Adobe Flash Player plugin
```

---

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg -l adobe-flashplugin ` and post the results!

Comment: You don't need sudo for dpkg -l, but I think `apt-cache policy adobe-flashplugin` would be better info here.

Comment: See this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Plugins/Roadmap

Answer (score 5):

Both Adobe and Mozilla are in process of phasing out Flash support.  By 2020, there will be no support from Adobe, and when security updates stop, Firefox will stop loading any version of the Flash Player.  In the meantime, it appears you must enable Flash Player (aka Shockwave Flash) individually for each website where you want to use it.  See the Mozilla announcement [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2017/07/25/firefox-roadmap-flash-end-life/).

The general recommendation is not to enable Flash unless a web site doesn't work without it, to "allow web sites to shine".  Above that, I'd recommend contacting web admins to let them know you want to continue to enjoy their content, but that they urgently need to begin the process of converting from Flash to HTML.  The 2020 Flash sunset will be here sooner than it seems.

Comment: Ok, i got it, it seems Flash is dead in Firefox, thanks for your answer! (Y)

Comment: Flash is *not* dead in Firefox, but it defaults to "off" for all websites until you specifically turn it on for each specific website.  Flash *will be dead in less than three years*, however, so it's time and past time to bury web admins in request to convert their content away from Flash.

Comment: @JeissonCadena  A new Firefox update arrived. Update and check whether it's working now. Working for me.

Comment: Flash is not dead and I have the same problem as @JeissonCadena. Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox 56 from today morning, Adobe Flash 27 with always active setting and no flash visible on any web pages. No messages in logs. Firefox 55 was working almost properly (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1394015), Firefox 54 was working without any issues. So it is some kind of issue.

Comment: OK, there were some new updates couple of minutes ago for Ubuntu 16.04 including some update for Firefox 56. And now it is working.

Comment: This is not a solution, specially if Mozilla and Adobe are supporting Flash Player in Ubuntu right now. Could be a comment for reference.

Comment: @leoperbo It's not a solution, it's an answer.  The answer is and will be that Flash is being dropped by all browsers due to long standing security and maintenance issues, and long term flash content will become obsolete everywhere.  Based on votes, it's the best answer for this question at present.  Let's see if yours gets more votes, but it won't change the fact that Flash is being sunsetted by both its maintainers and browser maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem since Firefox 56 (64 bits) in Ubuntu 17.10, I think is related to some workaround I applied from the lapse when Adobe dropped Flash Player support for Linux.

The solution is:

1. Install Flash Player via the `adobe-flashplugin` package (perhaps you need to activate Cannonical's Partners repositories in *Software and Updates*).
2. Run this command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-flashplugin
   ```
3. It'll show something like this (copy-paste from my case, I'm using spanish locales):

   ```
   Existen 2 opciones para la alternativa mozilla-flashplugin (que provee /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so).

   Selección   Ruta                                                                            Prioridad  Estado
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   * 0            /usr/lib/browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash/libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so   70        modo automático
    1            /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so                                     50        modo manual
    2            /usr/lib/browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash/libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so   70        modo manual

   Pulse <Intro> para mantener el valor por omisión [*] o pulse un número de selección:
   ```
4. I selected the option that points to `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so`, then, when I ran `sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-flashplugin` the output was:

   ```
   Existen 2 opciones para la alternativa mozilla-flashplugin (que provee /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so).

   Selección   Ruta                                                                            Prioridad  Estado
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   0            /usr/lib/browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash/libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so   70        modo automático
   * 1            /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so                                     50        modo manual
   2            /usr/lib/browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash/libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so   70        modo manual

   Pulse <Intro> para mantener el valor por omisión [*] o pulse un número de selección:
   ```
5. I rebooted and then Flash Player worked in Firefox Qantum.

Comment: This solution works on `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` with `Mozilla Firefox 65.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested workaround solution for now.

1. Head over to the [official Firefox download page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/).
2. Download the `tar bzip` package to your home directory.
3. Extract so you have `/home/username/firefox`
4. Make a shortcut on the desktop to Firefox, point it to `/home/username/firefox/firefox`

Enjoy flash until the official packages are updated.